# How can I unclutter Artists view in Banshee?

Tags: 11.04, banshee

I have huge [SXSW](http://sxsw.com/) compilation albums. They clutter Artists view. Clementine has an elegant solution for this — compilations are stored under *Various Artists*. How can I solve this in Banshee?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I filed this as bug two years ago, it was already filed as bug 4 years ago and the developers don't care. I am not sure whether they just don't understand the problem or they are too agitated with new features. I gave up hope and use guayadeque for the moment.

Comment: Sry, you google "banshee albumartist browser view" you should get some threads on it ...

Comment: @piedro: I was wondering about this, why don't they just fix it, you know?

Comment: @piedro can you give a link to your bug report, please. Gonna do some raging in comment section.

Comment: To be honest, I don't find my own reports anymore, don't know why, just found my rhythmbox stuff. And a lot of entries in various forums. But you may look at these (there's hope): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1647109 
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=540873
http://banshee-media-player.2283330.n4.nabble.com/Compilation-support-td2986734.html
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=624311

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your songs using <kbd>shift</kbd>+click then left click, choose edit track information, and choose "Various artists" for your songs. Then click the icon next to the artist.

> [image: pie]

**Keep in mind, if you have the option to save metadata to files enabled, that your files will have "Various Artists" as the artists!** So disable this option in preferences (unless this is what you want).

> [image]

Comment: Roland's answer is in fact correct. I just did not get this immediately — I thought it would wipe _Artist_ field. It actually writes data into _Album artist_ field.
Нowever, I think _Various Artists_ problem needs a better solution. You can find reasoning for that in comment by @piedro above. I reported this as an [explicit bug][1], just to be sure request is documented.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/776714

Comment: @skd: I agree, this bug needs to be sorted, I am similarly bothered by it :P